# How to set different expiration timeout for each new map entry using Google Guava?

Tags: java, guava

Google guava allows to set expiration timeout for each map enty using CacheBuilder. However I want to set different timeout for each new enty. Is is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible: expiration durations are set globally for the cache. You could create a feature request on the issue tracker, but exposing the right API for this might be complicated.